# Get time in linux without DST and with DST

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I want to know that is there any command which can provide time without DST if DST is applicable in the zone.

I have searched lot in google but not getting proper answer. I think there should be simple solution to get it.

Below is one link on stackoverflow.com but I am not getting 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123493/disable-daylight-saving-time-in-debian-linux

For example:
current time in Newyork is 
date
Wed Mar 23 04:51:54 EDT 2016

As per DST-free timezone definitions provided which just define the GMT-offset, called Etc/GMT±X:

TZ=Etc/GMT-1 date
Wed Mar 23 10:13:09 GMT-1 2016

Whereas DST is 1 hour forward on March 23 i.e. it should be ‎Wed, ‎Mar ‎23, ‎2016, ‏‎4:13 AM

Please anyone provide help.

Answer (score 0):

U.S. Eastern time is often represented by the time zone name "America/New_York" or "US/Eastern".  Equivalently, there is the "Posix" time zone name "EST5EDT".  The essential fact here is that this zone is nominally 5 hours off of UTC (or 4 hours when daylight saving time is in effect).

There are also some DST-free zone names of the form "UTC-4" and "UTC+5".

So if you say

```
export TZ="UTC+5"
date
```

You'll see the date in the equivalent of U.S. Eastern Standard Time, without a DST correction.

(This is essentially what the high-rated answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123493/disable-daylight-saving-time-in-debian-linux was trying to tell you, I think.)

If you wanted to take an arbitrary time zone name and construct from it an equivalent DST-free zone name, that'd be pretty tricky.